# How to hide a TextView from Specific listview item

Tags: android, android-studio, android-listview, android-listadapter

i´m new to android and im tryin to hide or show a Textview in my items from a listview from JSON.

The idea is to show and to custom a textview with a custom background and style if the date exists.

if date doesn't exist, then hide the textview in that item.

i know tha my be a realy stypid question, but i can't seem to find the right answer anyware.

[se here the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IG2uP.png)

**PrimerActivity.JAVA**

```
 public void showJSON(String response) {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Search_data_anuncios.JSON_ARRAY);

        for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
            String titulo = jo.getString(Search_data_anuncios.KEY_titulo_anuncio_cliente);
            String descripcion = jo.getString(Search_data_anuncios.KEY_descripcion_anuncio_cliente);
            String fecha_creacion = jo.getString(Search_data_anuncios.KEY_fecha_creacion_anuncio_cliente);
            String categoria_anuncio_cliente = jo.getString(Search_data_anuncios.KEY_categoria_anuncio_cliente);
            Log.i(TAG_activity, "AQUI - " + categoria_anuncio_cliente);
            //change_img_item(categoria_anuncio_cliente, i);

            final HashMap<String, String> oferta = new HashMap<>();
            oferta.put(Search_data_anuncios.KEY_titulo_anuncio_cliente,  titulo);
            oferta.put(Search_data_anuncios.KEY_descripcion_anuncio_cliente, descripcion);
            oferta.put(Search_data_anuncios.KEY_fecha_creacion_anuncio_cliente,  fecha_creacion);
            oferta.put(Search_data_anuncios.KEY_categoria_anuncio_cliente,  categoria_anuncio_cliente);

            list.add(oferta);

        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            PrimerActivity.this, list, R.layout.activity_anuncio_item_listview,
            new String[]{Search_data_anuncios.KEY_titulo_anuncio_cliente, Search_data_anuncios.KEY_descripcion_anuncio_cliente, Search_data_anuncios.KEY_fecha_creacion_anuncio_cliente, Search_data_anuncios.KEY_categoria_anuncio_cliente},
            new int[]{R.id.tv_titulo, R.id.tv_descripcion, R.id.tvclass});
    anunt.setAdapter(adapter);}
```

}

ACTIVITY_PRIMER.XML

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


  <ListView
      android:id="@+id/listView_anunt"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="57dp"
      android:dividerHeight="10dp">

  </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_anuncio_item_listview.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@color/black"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="111dp"
    android:layout_height="83dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_listview_img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/recuest2" />
</LinearLayout>



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_titulo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="txt tit"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.SearchResult.Title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_descripcion"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="txt des" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvclass"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="txt dat"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to change your adapter to another, for example **ArrayAdapter**. Inside **getView** method you can describe the logic for displaying what you need depending on the data. Below I showed an example, based on your datatype.

```
public class TestAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>> {
    public TestAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data) {
        super(context, 0, data);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_anuncio_item_listview, parent, false);
        }

        /*getting the model one by one*/
        HashMap<String, String> item = getItem(position);

        /*we get some view*/
        TextView textDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_descripcion);

        /*we get some value from model*/
        String testValue = item.get("tet_key");

        /*check if empty then hide the view*/
        if (testValue == null) {
            textDescription.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            textDescription.setText(testValue);

            textDescription.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

inside MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        HashMap<String, String> model1 = new HashMap<>();

        HashMap<String, String> model2 = new HashMap<>();
        model2.put("tet_key", "test");

        list.add(model1);
        list.add(model2);

        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView_anunt);
        TestAdapter adapter = new TestAdapter(this, list);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

result

[image]

*PS.I advise you to use instead of **ListView** -> **RecyclerView**,*  *and also instead of HashMap<*> it is better to use some model with fields and convert the data from the server to this model using GSON.

Comment: WOORKkkSSSSS!!! THANK YOU!!! 